# Docker not getting cached when installing requirements of Python and R

Tags: python, r, docker

I have a `Dockerfile` in which there are multiple commands, all get cached when unchanged. Although, there are two commands which never get cached regardless of any changes.

First one is a `python3` command and the other one is a `Rscript` command.

I tried reading about docker caching and all the related concepts but none of them addressed this strange behavior.

The two steps not getting cached are:

```
# install athena HEAD
RUN     python3 -m pip install -r aviral-py/requirements.txt
RUN     Rscript aviral-py/requirements/R_packages.R
ENV     RETICULATE_PYTHON="/opt/conda/bin/python3"
```

The first two commands in the above snippet run without making any changes.

The complete `Dockerfile` is [here](https://pastebin.com/yL7kzfY6)

I expect the commands to be cached when there are no changes in the corresponding files(the requirements files). I think I am missing a major concept in here.

Comment: In your full Dockerfile these `RUN` commands come after several `COPY`s (this is an important detail you should add to the question).  Are you sure none of those files you `COPY` in changed at all?

Comment: Could you paste a full log of two consecutive `docker image build ...` runs please? I tried to simulate, but it cashes here